# Corrupted USB drive with bad sectors

Tags: linux, filesystems, fdisk, gparted

I got a USB drive which is probably corrupted by some virus in windows. So, I tried formatting it by plugging it into an linux system. I used fdisk and gparted to try and delete all partitions and format the drive using **fdisk**. But I get the following errors:
[image: Errors]

Looking at the partition table of the disk, I noticed something very strange.

[image: Partition Table]

The drive is only around 4GB in size, but the some of the partitions are as large as 1TB.
What I concluded was that, fdisk could not write new partition table as it could not delete the existing partition tables probably because the starting point of the first partition itself is from a value(**778,135,908**) higher than that of the total sectors available(**7,897,087**).

So, is there anyway to change the start/end of the each partitions manually? so that I can finally clean format the drive and remove the virus.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track but the partition table  was corrupted. So, the first step is to create a new one (a DOS one in this example).

I assume your disk is /dev/sdx, please check this, because the next steps will erase the whole selected disk once you write to it (you have to explicitely ask `fdisk` to do it though).

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdx
```

There are many commands, you can type `m` to see them.

- Create a new DOS partition table by typing <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>
- Create a new partition typing <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, set it to primary <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>  and accept all default values. That will create a Linux partition that fills the disk.
- Type <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to finish `fdisk` and write the changes to disk (this is the moment the disk is written to).

You are almost there, a sane partition table and a single partition. You need to create the filesystem on that partition and you will be all set:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdx
```

Comment: dev/sdc: close device failed: Input/output error

This is what I get when I write changes from the first step.

Comment: And what do the last couple of lines of `sudo dmesg` show when that happens? It might be a hardware issue after all.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots say "disklabel type: dos", meaning MBR. The MBR is just the first 512 bytes of the drive, which can be manually overwritten with, say, `dd`.

But if you want to erase the entire drive and start over, an easy way to do that is

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdc
```

which completely zeros out the contents of the drive that `/dev/sdc` refers to. Then you should be able to (remove and reattach the drive and) reformat with the standard tools

Comment: Zeroing the whole drive looks like overkill, just erasing the MBR and partition would be enough.

Comment: and `dd` with a reasonably big block size is faster

Comment: definitely (to both of you)! this was an oversimplified answer that intentionally didn't go into detail on `dd` as a "quick get it working again". A more thorough answer that describes `dd` with explanation of good options would definitely be nice too

Comment: @fox I understand it. Following your advice, and seeing the OP had actually tried `fdisk` I added another answer.

Comment: I tried running sudo bash -c 'cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdc' and the command seems to be stuck however, I checked the disk activity using iotop it showed that cat /dev/zero is using write speeds upto 3MB/s.